# Utilize a function-based index while selecting additional columns

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-optimization, oracle18c

I have an Oracle 18c function-based index that works as expected:

1.Create a custom function that takes a [user-defined type](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/stgeometry-oracle.htm) object, and returns a list of coordinates as text:

```
create or replace function endpoint_list(shape in sde.st_geometry) return varchar2 
deterministic is
    coord_list varchar2(4000);
begin
    coord_list := 
      --sde.st_geometry functions are notoriously slow.  
      sde.st_geometry_operators.st_x_f(sde.st_geometry_operators.st_startpoint_f(sde.st_geometry_operators.st_geometryn_f(shape,1))) || ',' || 
            sde.st_geometry_operators.st_y_f(sde.st_geometry_operators.st_startpoint_f(sde.st_geometry_operators.st_geometryn_f(shape,1))) || ',' || 
                sde.st_geometry_operators.st_x_f(sde.st_geometry_operators.st_endpoint_f(  sde.st_geometry_operators.st_geometryn_f(shape,1))) || ',' ||
                    sde.st_geometry_operators.st_y_f(sde.st_geometry_operators.st_endpoint_f(  sde.st_geometry_operators.st_geometryn_f(shape,1)));
return coord_list; 
end;
```

2.Create a function-based index (FBI) on the custom function:

```
create index atn_endpoint_list_idx on my_owner.active_transportation(my_owner.endpoint_list(shape));
```

3.Run a query that uses the FBI in the SELECT clause:

```
select  
    endpoint_list(shape) as list
from
    active_transportation --15,000 rows
where
    endpoint_list(shape) is not null


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                       |   727 |   299K|    50  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| ATN_ENDPOINT_LIST_IDX |   727 |   299K|    50  (10)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("my_owner"."ENDPOINT_LIST"("SHAPE") IS NOT NULL)
```

That FBI works as expected. When I select `endpoint_list(shape)` as a column, the query uses the index, cutting the run time down from 65 seconds to .09 seconds. Good.

---

In addition to selecting `endpoint_list(shape)`, I also want to select other columns from the table, such as the OBJECTID column:

```
select  
    objectid,  --Note: OBJECTID has a index of it's own (unique).
    endpoint_list(shape) as list
from
    active_transportation
where
    endpoint_list(shape) is not null

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                       |   727 |   299K|   181   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| ACTIVE_TRANSPORTATION |   727 |   299K|   181   (4)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("my_owner"."ENDPOINT_LIST"("SHAPE") IS NOT NULL)
```

Now, the FBI is ***not*** being used. The query does a full table scan instead, which isn't what I want.

---

Question:

How can I utilize a function-based index while selecting additional columns?

Comment: When you add columns not in the index, the db has to read the table after reading the index. And as in your case the optimizer thinks it will return all the rows, it is easier for the db to just read the table. Try to gather stats to see if it changes the cost and estimated rows in both cases.

Comment: @gsalem Thanks. Your comment helped a lot. I posted an answer where I use a composite index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the additional column (OBJECTID) to the index — as a composite index:

```
create index atn_endpoint_list_idx on
    my_owner.active_transportation(my_owner.endpoint_list(shape),OBJECTID);
--
```

Now, the FBI is being used:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                       |   727 |   299K|    53  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| ATN_ENDPOINT_LIST_IDX |   727 |   299K|    53  (10)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("my_owner"."ENDPOINT_LIST"("SHAPE") IS NOT NULL)
```